How to combine skip content behavior with displaying accordion collapsed?
I've an accordion by bootstrap in content and an anchor tag in a summary. I want skip content when I click on item of summary, it was the current behavior. But I would also like to set bootstrap attributes, which handles the opening/ closing of an accordion-item:
 data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse_{{ id }}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse_{{ id }}"

on my <a href="#skip-content"></a>
But when I put them on anchor tag, the skip content behavior no longer works.
How I can combine the 2 behaviors? Are they compatible?
